# Label and textbox on the same line + textbox on the whole width

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

By default in ASP.NET MVC, when the system generate views (scaffolding) we have the label on one line and the textbox on the next line. I would like to have the label and the textbox on the same line and having the textbox on the whole width (100%). I try to achieve this without success.

I found some similar posts but not allowing me to have the textbox on the whole width!

Here is what I want:

[image]

So, by default I have:

```
<div class="editor-label"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descr) </div>
<div class="editor-field"> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descr) </div>

<div class="editor-label"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Year) </div>
<div class="editor-field"> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Year) </div>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a purely HTML/CSS question that has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. I would recommend you the [following article](http://speckyboy.com/2009/07/02/20-resources-and-tutorials-for-creative-forms-using-css/) for creating nice HTML forms with CSS.

So in your case you could `float: left` the label and define it a fixed width. Just as illustrated in [this live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YkrQp/1/) I wrote for you:

```
.editor-label {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

.editor-field {
    margin-left: 200px;
}

.editor-field input {
    width: 100%;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the correct answer:both label and textboxes are in the same line

.editor-label{  
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom:-20px;
}

.editor-field
{
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-bottom:-5px;

}
.display-label {
    float: left; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 160px;
}
```